# Resharper - use object initializer refactor - how to retain parentheses on constructor call?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, object-initializers

When I use Resharper to refactor my code to use an Object initializer, it reformats the code correctly as thus, the following code

```
var response = new Response(); 
response.Value = "My value";
```

becomes

```
var response = new Response
{
   Value = "My value",
};
```

I can't find anyplace in Resharper options where I can set it up to retain the parentheses as part of the constructor code (which I prefer for consistency).  Is it possible?  I would like Resharper to format it thus:

```
var response = new Response()
{
   Value = "My value",
};
```

Comment: If this does not exist, this would be a feature request for the product.

Comment: R# treats these parentheses as redundant (because they really are). I guess disabling the redundant parentheses inspection might help?

Comment: given they *are* redundant, why do you want to keep them?

Comment: @PeterRitchie He already explained that.. "which I prefer for consistency"

Comment: "Consistency" with what?  These are object initializers, they are different from just constructor invocation--there is no inherent "consistency".  If anything, including the "()" is "inconsistent" because they are initializers and not just constructor invocations.

Comment: Consistency with ordinary constructors.  Initializers are not different from constructor invocation in that the constructor is still called; I think it would be bad practice to be inconsistent with the syntax, as code exists first to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute.

Comment: @HighCore, I tried disabling "Remove redundant parentheses" in Context Actions, but I think this just omits it as a context choice. In any case, this didn't affect the behavior I noted. Anywhere else I can look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this feature is not available in Resharper.